# How can I check whether a SVM classifier delivers "degenerate" predictions?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, unbalanced-classes

If I fit an SVM to imbalanced data (e.g. two classes and a sample where more than 90% belong to class 1 and only 10% to class 2) it may happen that the classifier simply classifies all cases as class 1.
This problem can be handled by specifying costs and/or resampling, but I would like to know whether the classifier has such a simple form.
Is there a way to check for this in a "simple" form (e.g. by looking at output objects in Python Scikit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the most straight-forward way of identifying such a problem is having a look at the actual predicitons of the model. Generating a [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) of your models predictions is a standard procedure for this purpose and is [implemented in scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html).
Having a look at the [example in the wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix#Example) helps interpreting the confusion matrix, which tells us: it shows us that 5 instances of class 'Cat' have been correctly classified as such, while 3 have been wrongly classified as 'Dog'.

If your model is really struggling with the class imbalance in the data, then you will see most instances predicted as the majority class - many wrongly so.